# Detecting biasing columns and removing bias in machine learning

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multivariate-analysis

I came across a multivariate machine learning problem in which I need to detect the biasing column and remove the bias of that particular column in predicting final target variable. train data-> [x1,x2,..xn,BiasColumn,y] (BiasColumn does not contain all the X columns. Its only a fixed subset of X). What should be the standard way to approach this problem?

Comment: I thought of an approach as:
1)Create classification model for detecting bias column 
2)training a separate model for each value in BiasColumns. So in each model we will only take the training data subset having a particular biascolumn. We remove that column from X and train the model on y
3)for predictions we first detect the biascolumn and select the respective regression model for y

Comment: What exactly is meant by bias of a column? Each column is more useful or less useful at predicting a target. Any bias may come exclusively from the method that uses the columns to predict the target. Are you perhaps saying that your specific model performs better when a certain column is excluded from predictors?